# SearchBox Background Color

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I have a form for adding an item. The item requires an author which could be search, in which the component for the author was a search box. Also included a code in which the background of the search box will turn red when empty otherwise white. Also have a list for suggestion. When the time I select an author in the suggestions, the search box don't turn it's color. But when I hover the search box, that's the only time it goes to the costumed color. No user want's to hover the search box every time just to see if it is valid or not.

Here's a sample code:

**XAML**

```
<SearchBox x:Name="SearchBoxColor" SearchHistoryEnabled="False" SuggestionsRequested="SearchBoxColor_SuggestionsRequested" QueryChanged="SearchBoxColor_QueryChanged" QuerySubmitted="SearchBoxColor_QuerySubmitted" Background="White" />
<Button Content="Turn Color"Click="ButtonColor_Click" />
```

**CS**

```
private void SearchBoxColor_SuggestionsRequested(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args) {
    // When this event is called the background will change instantly
    ChangeSearchBoxColor();
}

private void SearchBoxColor_QueryChanged(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxQueryChangedEventArgs args) {
    // When this event is called the background will change instantly
    ChangeSearchBoxColor();
}

private void SearchBoxColor_QuerySubmitted(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args) {
    // When this event is called the background will change instantly
    ChangeSearchBoxColor();
}

private void ButtonColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // When this event is called the background will change only when the search box is hovered
    ChangeSearchBoxColor();
}

private void ChangeSearchBoxColor() {
    SearchBoxColor.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

Comment: So are you looking for something that turns the search box red when there is no text and when there is, it should return to normal?

Comment: Just call `ChangeSearchBoxColor();` when loading the page, before requiring the user to interact with the search box.

Comment: Yes I want to change the color of search box depending on the QueryText, but with event triggered by other component not by its own event. Yes I just called the `ChangeSearchBoxColor()` within every event but still it only change it's color when hovered for events owned by other component. Sample codes are given above question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with code-behind on your view which would set the background to the red color you're looking for however I'd recommend using the Behaviors SDK, which you can reference in your 8.1 project, to set a VisualState on the control if the text is invalid. You can do this as follows:

**Action:**

```
public class SearchBoxTextErrorVisualStateAction : DependencyObject, IAction
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ErrorVisualStateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ErrorVisualState",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(SearchBoxTextErrorVisualStateAction),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string ErrorVisualState
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this.GetValue(ErrorVisualStateProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ErrorVisualStateProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidVisualStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ValidVisualState",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(SearchBoxTextErrorVisualStateAction),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string ValidVisualState
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this.GetValue(ValidVisualStateProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ValidVisualStateProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        var searchBox = sender as SearchBox;

        if (searchBox != null)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(
                searchBox,
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchBox.QueryText) ? this.ErrorVisualState : this.ValidVisualState,
                true);
        }

        return parameter;
    }
}
```

**XAML example:**

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="AppErrorColor">#FFD32F2F</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeErrorShade" Color="{ThemeResource AppErrorColor}" />

        <Style x:Key="SearchBoxStyle" TargetType="SearchBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="SearchBox">
                        <Grid x:Name="SearchBoxGrid">
                            ...

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBoxGrid">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBoxBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBoxGrid">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SearchBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBoxBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SearchBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SearchBoxDisabledTextThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchTextBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ErrorStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextInvalid">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBoxGrid">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ThemeErrorShade}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextValid">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBoxGrid">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBoxBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            ...
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <SearchBox Style="{StaticResource SearchBoxStyle}">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
                    <actions:SearchBoxTextErrorVisualStateAction ErrorVisualState="TextInvalid" ValidVisualState="TextValid" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="QueryChanged">
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
                    <actions:SearchBoxTextErrorVisualStateAction ErrorVisualState="TextInvalid" ValidVisualState="TextValid" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </SearchBox>
</Grid>
```

Due to the limits of answers, I can't paste the entirety of the XAML but you want to add the default SearchBox to your view, in the design window, right click it and go to 'Edit Template -> Edit a copy'. It will create a copy of the default style in which you can replace the root Grid's VisualStateGroups with the ones above.

Edit: The reason for firing the action on the Loaded event is so that you can enable the color change when the control is brought into view and not just when the text changes.

Comment: I want to change the background color of the search box on a button click. On my code, searchbox events turns it right. But when I call the method on another event, color changing only applies when the searchbox is hovered. Using your code displays the same result. I thought Loaded event will help but still the same.